# font file not found in libgdx gwt web application

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx

I've almost got my libgdx project running as a web application through gwt, but it keeps crashing when it tries to load a font file.  I've found people with similar problems, but their solutions don't seem to be working for me.

This is the suspect line where the crash is occurring:

```
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/test.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/test_0.tga"), false, true);
```

I'm using Gdx.files.internal so that it doesn't try to use the classpath when searching for the assets, but it still isn't finding it.  I know I've linked my assets correctly, because it plays my start up sound before crashing.  And also, because of this status (Note that test_0.tga is in the list):

```
...
loaded data/backgrounds/Splash.png,3/38
loaded data/fonts/test.fnt,5/38
loaded data/fonts/test_0.tga,6/38
loaded data/maps/DrillHead.map,8/38
loaded data/maps/PowerPlant.map,9/38
...
```

But I can't seem to stop it from getting this error:

```
GwtApplication: exception: Couldn't load image 'data/fonts/test_0.tga', file does not exist
Couldn't load image 'data/fonts/test_0.tga', file does not exist
```

I saw one person had said to use Gdx.files.local instead of Gdx.files.internal, but when I tried this, I got this error when it reached the command.

```
GwtApplication: exception: Not supported in GWT backend
Not supported in GWT backend
```

I'm running this from Eclipse 4.2, and I've done a full Project -> Clean..., and my project does a -strict GWT Compile with no errors.  I am completely stumped on what feels like such a minor issue after all the hoops I've jumped through to get this working to this point.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  Also, I put a simple System.out.println(Gdx.files.internal("data/fonts/test_0.tga")) right before the line where the error occurs, and it returns true.  Why is it saying it cannot find the file under this specific circumstance?

Answer (score 3):

I swear I'm not doing this on purposed.  It looks like for whatever reason GWT does not support tga files.  I converted my test_0.tga file to a png file, and it is now working.  If anyone finds this via google, I hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, tga files are not supported by browsers in general.